# JUnit Mockito Testing and Spying 2 separate methods

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, stub

I have a service class that I want to write junit tests for. Here is that service class:

```
public class FooService {
  private BarService barService;

  public FooService(BarService barService) {
    this.barService = barService;
  }

  public Foo methodOne(int a) {
    double value = methodTwo();
    //do some other stuff and return Foo
  }

  public double methodTwo() {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Here's my junit test:

```
public class FooServiceTest {
  @Mock
  BarService barService;
  FooService fooService;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    fooService = Mockito.spy(new FooService(barService));
    doReturn(1.0).when(fooService).methodTwo();
    doCallRealMethod().when(fooService).methodOne(1);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    fooService.methodOne(1);
    assertThat(.....)
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I run my test it never actually calls `methodOne`. It just skips everything in the `FooService` and goes directly to the `asserThat(...)` line. I have a feeling it has something to do with Spying on the fooService object.

How can I write a junit test for this FooService where I make a real call to `methodOne` but I mock the return of `methodTwo`?

Comment: I have tried this code, and the real `methodOne` is invoked. Can you add `System.out.println("methodOne called");` in `methodOne(int a)` and check if it prints out?

Comment: is it necessary to mock just the methodTwo? Must methodTwo() be public or you change it only for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you made it a bit complicated. And you were right about `spy` :

```
public class FooService {

    BarService barService;

    public FooService(BarService barService) {
        this.barService = barService;
    }

    public String methodOne(int a) {
        double value = methodTwo();
        return "Hello from method 1 - " + value;
    }

    public double methodTwo() {
        return 1;
    }
}


public class MyTest {

    private BarService barService = Mockito.mock(BarService.class);
    private FooService fooService = Mockito.spy(new FooService(barService));

    @Test
    void test() {
       doReturn(7.0).when(fooService).methodTwo();
       String result = fooService.methodOne(1);
       assertThat(result).isEqualTo("Hello from method 1 - 7.0");
    }

}
```

If you are using spies all not mocked methods will be "real" ones. So no need to say `doCallRealMethod()`.